# F# struct discriminant union interop with C#: casting to a specific case

Tags: f#

With a reference discriminant union like

```
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of 'T
    | Error of 'TError
```

you can cast to one of the cases in C# like `var error = (Result<T,TError>.Error) result` but that doesn't compile with the equivalent struct discriminant union.

How can you cast to a specific case of struct discriminant union in C# interop scenarios? Or, how are struct discriminant union cases represented in CLR types?

Comment: With struct DUs you can write an exhaustive switch expression in C# 8 but it doesn't feel natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's no equivalent struct DU. The compiler will force you to give name to the fields when switching to a struct DU.

```
[<Struct>]
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of 'T
    | Error of 'TError
;;

  type Result<'T,'TError> =
  -----^^^^^^

error FS3204: If a union type has more than one case and is a struct, 
then all fields within the union type must be given unique names.
```

So, you can translate it like:

```
[<Struct>]
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of ok: 'T
    | Error of error: 'TError
```

This will create a struct with two fields `ok` and `error` of the corresponding type, actually it's a bit more complex as it will create internals backing fields and present you those names as properties. See it in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPg2gPAZQC4CcCuBjJA+AugWACgkBPABwFMACAJQojWCTgHIAVAGnYFEUUB7FNioBeIlQlUoVAPIBrKvzCK5IKu3GTpvASkXKKfQWp5GUQA==) for more details.

So, you'll be able to access the properties like:

```
var error = result.error;
```

Comment: [Sharlab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFBH4bYBK6EArsEQDwDkAKlDwKIAnQckEA+bAF4q2WdkTYA8gGtsyMNh4y5CoSMFqNA4aKpA) returns a different class - base `Result` class with two `inner` concrete classes.

Comment: Yes, when it's not a struct DU. But it looks like he already knows that.

Comment: Missed the `struct` and ... oops. I see there'll be some interop issues when C# 9 comes out. The code is completely different. Still usable with pattern matching, just very different than the natural patterns.

Comment: Let's hope they fix it before !

Comment: the two results are completely different, so it won't be easy without either modifying the F# compiler or also generating different code in C# 9. I don't see that happening

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the design of the compiled DUs (both ref and struct ones) were done with interop in mind. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: They weren't. But now they'll have to interoperate. F# will have handle C# DUs, especially any `Result` type, although I expect *consuming* will be easier in F#

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sharplab.io to see [what the F# generates behind the scenes](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFBH4bYBK6EArsEQDwDkAKlDwKIAnQckEA+bAF4q2WdkTYA8gGtsyMNh4y5CoSMFqNA4aKpA) for this type :

```
public abstract class Result<T, TError> : IEquatable<Result<T, TError>>, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable<Result<T, TError>>, IComparable, IStructuralComparable
{
    public static class Tags
    {
        public const int Ok = 0;

        public const int Error = 1;
    }

    public class Ok : Result<T, TError>
    {
        internal readonly T item;

        public T Item =>item;

        internal Ok(T item) { this.item = item;}
    }

    public class Error : Result<T, TError>
    {
        internal readonly TError item;

        public TError Item => item;

        internal Error(TError item) { this.item = item; }
    }

    ...
    public int Tag  => (this is Error) ? 1 : 0;

    public bool IsOk=> this is Ok;

    public bool IsError =>this is Error;

}
```

The F# compiler *generates* an abstract .NET base class `Result<T, TError>` with the concrete cases as inner classes: `Result<T, TError>.Ok` and `Result<T, TError>.Error`.

You could use pattern matching to match each of the concrete types, switch on the `Tag` property or check the `IsOk` or `IsError properties, eg:

```
public string SomeMethod(Result<int,string> input)
{
    return input switch { Result<int,string>.Ok    ok =>$"Number: {ok.Item}",
                          Result<int,string>.Error err=>err.Item ,
                          - => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to write an exhaustive switch expression for this yet. The [discriminated union proposal for C# 9](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/discriminated-unions.md) uses the same pattern (base enum class with concrete cases), so this will probably be fixed in C# 9.

In C# 8 you can use property patterns to extract the contained value (result or error) :

```
public string SomeMethod(Result<int,string> input)
{
    return input switch { 
        Result<int,string>.Ok    {Item: var ok}  =>$"Number: {ok*100}",
        Result<int,string>.Error {Item: var err} =>err ,
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };
}
```

In C# versions that can't use pattern matching, you can switch on the `Tag` property. The result isn't nice but at least it works :

```
switch(input.Tag)
{
    case Result<int,string>.Tags.Ok:
        ...
        break;
    case Result<int,string>.Tags.Error:
        ...
        break;
    default: 
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

**Update - Struct**

I missed the `struct` part. In that case [the code is completely different](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFADaAPLkQE4CuAxkQHwC6VR+G2AEroIzYEVoByACpQZAUUaNkjDtgC8VbNuyJsAeQDW2ZGBOGQ2GVp17FyxibPolKywteMqQA==) - one flat `struct` with all properties on it :

```
   public struct Result<T, TError> 
    {
        public static class Tags
        {
            public const int Ok = 0;

            public const int Error = 1;
        }


        public int Tag {get;}

        public bool IsOk =>Tag == 0;

        public bool IsError=>Tag == 1;
        public T ok {get;}

        public TError error {get;}

        public static Result<T, TError> NewOk(T _ok)
        {
            return new Result<T, TError>(_ok, 0, false);
        }

        public static Result<T, TError> NewError(TError _error)
        {
            return new Result<T, TError>(_error, 1, 0);
        }

        internal Result(T _ok, int _tag, bool P_2)
        {
            this.ok = _ok;
            this.Tag = _tag;
            this.error=default;
        }

        internal Result(TError _error, int _tag, byte P_2)
        {
            this.error = _error;
            this.Tag = _tag;
            this.ok=default;
        }

}
```

That's a blessing and a curse. On the one hand, now we *can* create an exhaustive switch expression :

```
string x=(input.IsOk,input.ok,input.error) switch { 
          (true,var ok,_)  =>$"Number: {ok*100}",
          (false,_,var err)  =>err 
};
```

On the other hand, that's not the most intuitive expression. It's probably going to break when C# 9 DU's come out too. C# 9 could use the *original* pattern, using default interface members for the base class and its members. The F# compiler would have to change to use the new syntax.